# Expression for someone with very broad and detailed knowledge

Tags: expression, idiom, phrase-request

Are there any well-known German expressions for someone who is very board and detailed in knowledge? for example:

> He is a human database

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's

> Sie ist ein wandelndes Lexikon.

Sometimes also used in this form

> Sie ist ein lebendes Lexikon.

Comment: +1 for _wandelndes Lexikon_ (I've never lived in a region where the other version is used).

Answer (score 6):

One option would be "der/die Universalgelehrte" from the English word "polymath".

Answer (score 3):

There is also the exppression "Hansdampf in allen Gassen."

Comment: From which region is this? As a Rheinisch person I'd have no idea what this meant.

Answer (score 2):

I think both [Alleskönner](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Alleskoenner) and [Tausendsassa](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tausendsassa) could fit as well, if a more colloquial term is needed. [Multitalent](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Multitalent) would be another option.

Answer (score 0):

The word I would use is "savant." It was originally French, may have been adopted in German, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It is sometimes used in German, but only for who are "savant" due to Asperger syndrome, as far as I know.

Comment: I suspect a lot of Germans wouldn't be familiar with that term. I've certainly never heard it used.

Comment: You can use that (the german word is "Inselbegabter"), but it doesn't describe someone with a broad knowledge. Savants are often mentally retarded, but have one particular skill that is far better than that of normal people. That can be perfectly playing music just after hearing a piece once or reciting a telephone book after reading it once. A savant is also not necessarily an autistic person.